# How to retain the pagination number, after reloading the page

Tags: angular

I am using Angular PrimeNG Paginator Component (i.e `p-paginator`).

The HTML part of the code looks like :

```
<div class="paginator paginator-product mb-5">
        <p-paginator [rows]="12" pageLinkSize="6" [alwaysShow]="false" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
          [totalRecords]="totalRecords" #paginator (onPageChange)="onPageChange($event)"></p-paginator>
      </div>
```

**Here the issue is that, suppose current page is on 6th index, when I am reloading the page, it gets back to 1 (the position of the page is not retaining)**

[image]

Is there any way, that I can retain the page number even after reloading the page OR make the paginator to get selected at a particular index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <p-paginator [rows]="1" [first]="6" [alwaysShow]="false" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
      [totalRecords]="totalRecords" #paginator (onPageChange)="onPageChange($event)"></p-paginator>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is still not retaining the page number.

Comment: set [rows]="1" with [first]="6"